# Element position, depending on its dimensions

Tags: css, layout, css-position

I got some problems with avatars on my website, when there is a `35`x`35` avatar, then its ok , problem appear as you know, when the `35x35` pixel dimensions has been exceeded.

I think it's related with the `position: absolute;` attribute, but couldnt find any better replacement for this.

Here is a live demo, of what I'm asking for: http://jsfiddle.net/AtJVb/0/

As you can see, avatar is too big - but the elements around still stay at their positions, instead to be moved around.

Here is a live demo with `35 x 35` image: http://jsfiddle.net/AtJVb/1/

Here, everything is perfect, and I want my first example, to look exactly the same (I mean those author, date and comment content elements positions), but with the bigger image size.

Waiting for ANY solution, I'd appreciate.

Comment: Why don't you tell the avatar that he should be `width: 35px; height: 35px;`? Or you want it to be chaotic every avatar being a different size?

Comment: @bažmegakapa Basicly, the dimensions will be between `1x1 - 100x100` pixels and not bigger, it wont be very chatic at all. I just need that avatar to be in one place and the text around to fit the rest of the content.

Comment: You could simply `float: left` that avatar, and `clear: left` the comment body. Absolute positioning messes it up here.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Oh, thanks. Great idea. Why don't you post this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply `float: left` that avatar, and `clear: left` the comment body.

Absolute positioning messes it up here.

> an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and
>   thus takes up no space when placing other elements.

from [MDN - Absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)